# Why doesnt this page load?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

I can't get the following page to load although i've tried lots of things.

https://www.youtube.com/user/sfrfreestyle?x=us-en_sfr_187_3

I am running 4.0.1 web bundle (Windows 7). The main part of the page loads but not the youtube playlist video part.

I' tried:

- allowing scipts in noscrip;
- delete noscript from the addons;
- installed quick java - activated js, ja and f;
- several new identities;
- installed Tor version 4.0 and 3.6.6;
- tested the page in chrome and firefox - worked there;
- installed adobe flash for firefox and set it to allways activated in tor;
- normal youtube playlists work;

Nothing worked.
ill update this when I find new possible solutions or the final solution.

Comment: What is behind the bit.ly URL?

Comment: @tichodroma 
behind the bit.ly url is just the same youtube url. i can delete it if it looks suspicius or weird - its just the link I used when i stumbled into the problem first so i thought id add it but it makes no difference - im not sure but i guess they just use it to shorten the second one? :)

Comment: works for me ...

Comment: What do you mean you can't get it to load? You can't play the flash video, or the page doesn't load at all? Do you get some error? Is part of the page loading?

Comment: @samwhited the lower part of the page loads - the comments and stuff - but the actuall youtube playlist doesnt show up - the part with the videos in. theres this turning circle symbol of little dots similar to the apple ball of death thingy.